# How to make a postgreSQL image postGIS enabled using a Dockerfile ?

Tags: docker

I have been given a task of makeing a [postgreSQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), postGIS enabled. So basically has i figured out after reading the Docker documentation, That i have to pull the image of postgreSQL and run it locally and than i have to enable postGIS.

If you actually check the Docker hub, there is already an image of postgreSQL being postGIS enabled, [HERE](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/~/dockerfile/).

My requirement is such that i need to start from scratch and actually make a docker file that will make my postgreSQL image postGIS enabled. So my question is how would i go about doing this, what would the process of making a postgreSQL image postGIS enabled involve ? Where do i start at all(Please note i need to do this using a Dockerfile) ? So basically my question is how do i make a postgreSQL image postGIS enabled using a DockerFile ?

Comment: From scratch as in [`FROM scratch`](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/)?

Comment: NO ! https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=OrLgUqXiLYi3kAfI3ICYDw#q=from+scratch+meaning+ :D

Comment: Think about how  you would do it on a Linux PC. You have to automate all that in a Dockerfile. Some things are not easy to automate, so you will do it manually, and then `docker commit`this image, and your Dockerfile will continue with `FROM my_image`

Comment: @user2915097 `Think about how you would do it on a Linux PC` , did you mean , think about how i would it do it normally from the terminal ?

Comment: yes exactly, you need to automate all that

Comment: @user2915097 , just to re-iterate what you said , i shoudl think about how i would build the image on the terminal and than go ahead and build my Dockerfile accordingly ? , thats what you suggest ?

Comment: Yes, as in a Dockerfile you can use COPY /ADD to copy files from remote or your PC, RUN to do anything in a terminal, and so

Comment: Err, why can't you use the Dockerfile you linked to? Or at least copy the steps? This is very confusing.

Comment: @AdrianMouat , i had the same idea !! , but still wanted to ask the question `How to make a postgreSQL image postGIS enabled using a Dockerfile ?` , so the linked Dockerfile , is everything i would need you think ? (sorry for my totally noob questions , i am a total begineer.)

Comment: Try it and come back if you have any problems. It sounds like you're best working through a tutorial or something first though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Dockerfile](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis/blob/develop/Dockerfile) creates a Postgres image with PostGIS enabled from scratch, which means based on an Ubuntu image as you would do it on a bare-metal Ubuntu machine or an Ubuntu VM in VMware or Virtualbox.

Try to understand the commands in the `Dockerfile` using the [official Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) and feel free to come back with specific questions if you need further help.